# Access grub rescue from boot: menu

Tags: boot, grub2

I'd like to access a grub prompt while booting an Ubuntu 12.04 ISO with Virtualbox.

When keeping the left Shift key pressed while booting, or when pressing `Esc`, I get stuck in some weird prompt named `boot:`

Here are some commands I tried:

```
boot: ls
Could not find kernel image: ls

boot: help
Could not find kernel image: help

boot: .
Invalid or corrupt kernel image.
```

When pressing `Enter` (empty command) the system boots.

What is this prompt? What commands does it accept? How can I gain a grub prompt from this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the [`syslinux`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/syslinux) prompt.

> If the Shift or Alt keys are held down during boot, or the Caps or
>   Scroll locks are set, syslinux will display a lilo(8) -style "boot:"
>   prompt.

You can't access grub from this, but you can press `Tab` to see what options are accepted.

```
boot: <press Tab>
 live

boot: live
<system booting>
```

The prompt also accepts kernel command line arguments:

```
boot: live quiet splash
```

Note that his prompt may be very old but there is no way to check its version.